# Transform Object in another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Anyone can help me with this object?
I'm gonna receive a object like this:

```
NewImage: {
          sourceId: {
            S: "some_string"
          },
          ignored: {
            BOOL: false
          },
          stepFunctionArn: {
            S: "some_string"
          },
          certificate: {
            BOOL: true
          },
          infoNeeded: {
            L: [
              "Array"
            ]
          },
          queuesLinks: {
            M: [
              "Object"
            ]
          },
        }
```

How can i remove those "S", "BOOL" before each value? I need a object like this:

```
NewImage: {
  sourceId: "some_string",
  ignored: false,
  stepFunctionArn: "some_string"
  ...
}
```

I need to make a function that convert that object like i explain above.
Any ideas?
Thanks for the help : )

Comment: do you have only a single property in the most nested objects?

Comment: It looks like queuesLinks is supposed to be transformed into an object, but it would need some property names for the values.  What's wrong with using regular JSON this looks like someone tried to reinvent it.

Comment: its a response of dynamodb stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take the values from the nested objects.

```js
const
    data = { sourceId: { S: "some_string" }, ignored: { BOOL: false }, stepFunctionArn: { S: "some_string" }, certificate: { BOOL: true }, infoNeeded: { L: ["Array"] }, queuesLinks: { M: ["Object"] } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, o]) => [k, Object.values(o)[0]])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please could you explain what is happening on the .map() line?

Comment: it take the entries as key value pairs and returns a new array with the key and the first value from the nested object.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense to me now.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why we cannot use data.map directly? ultimately Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data)) is converted to the same object only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
Object.keys(NewImage).forEach(key=>{
 NewImage[key]=NewImage[key][Object.keys(NewImage[key])[0]];
});
console.log(NewImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a new object with the indicated structure you can try this:

```
const newObj = Object.keys(NewImage).reduce((curr, next) => {
  const key = Object.keys(NewImage[next])[0];
  curr[next] = NewImage[next][key];
  return curr; 
}, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach using reduce method!

```
const data = {
    sourceId: {
        S: "some_string"
    },
    ignored: {
        BOOL: false
    },
    stepFunctionArn: {
        S: "some_string"
    },
    certificate: {
        BOOL: true
    },
    infoNeeded: {
        L: [
            "Array"
        ]
    },
    queuesLinks: {
        M: [
            "Object"
        ]
    },
};
const newObject = Object.entries(data).reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  accumulator[currentValue[0]] = Object.values(currentValue[1])[0];

  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(newObject)
```